# How to draw a rectangle around the current cursor's position in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

I am trying to draw a rectangle around the current cursor's position in MFC. It works when I move the mouse but the rectangle is disappeared when I stop moving the mouse.

```
void CView1::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if (!m_mouse_tracking)
    {
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER;
        tme.hwndTrack = this->m_hWnd;
        tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;

        if (::_TrackMouseEvent(&tme))
        {
            m_mouse_tracking = true;

            // Draw the 1st rect
            draw_rect_(m_pDC);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Draw new rect and erase old rect
        RedrawWindow(NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
        draw_rect_(m_pDC);
    }
}

void CView1::OnMouseHover(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    m_mouse_tracking = false;

    draw_rect_(m_pDC);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my source code? Please, help me.

Comment: You call `RedrawWindow` to invalidate the client area, which will cause a repaint some time _after_ `draw_rect_()` has returned. That's propably not what you expected. Try `RDW_UPDATENOW`, but actually you should do all painting in `WM_PAINT` while anywhere else you only *invalidate* the client area.

Comment: Is `m_pDC` a memory DC? Is there a memory bitmap? Give more information about the variables and functions, if not [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If the rectangle is small enough, isn't changing the cursor itself a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do your painting in your [CView1::OnPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01c9aaty.aspx) method.

Also, you can use [CDC::SetROP2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class#setrop2) method using `R2_NOTXORPEN` instead of invalidating the entire window, [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7311935-4113-4e3a-bc7b-5126b9965044/drawing-a-rectangle-over-a-bitmap-c-win32-programming?forum=vcgeneral) has an example.